# Simple Opengl Triangle on mavericks

Tags: macos, opengl

I am new at opengl. I am starting with a simple triangle using GLFW , but I dont get anything drawn. 
My system is :
OSX Mavericks 10.9.2 Intel HD 4000
compilation cmd line: 
g++  main.cpp -o Test  -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib  -lglfw -framework Opengl

First thing I noticed odd was, on compilation , it did not identify
glGenVertexArrays , and suggested: glGenVertexArraysAPPLE same for:glBindVertexArray and suggested: glBindVertexArrayAPPLE
On using APPLE ext , didnt draw anything.

What am I missing here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <string.h>

GLuint vao=0;
GLuint shader_programme;

void CheckGLErrors(std::string str)
{
    int errCount = 0;
    GLenum currError = glGetError();
    if(currError != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        //Do something with `currError`.
        std::cout<<"\n"<<str<<" Error raised:"<<currError<<"\n";
    }
}

void initVertex()
{
    float points[] = {
        0.0f,  0.5f,  0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f,
       -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f
    };

static const float colors[] =
{
    1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0
};

    glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(1, &vao);    
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE (vao);    

    GLuint vbo = 0;
    glGenBuffers (1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9 * sizeof (float), points, GL_STATIC_DRAW);  
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);    
    glVertexAttribPointer (0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);

    const char* vertex_shader =
    "#version 400\n"
    "in vec3 vp;"
    "void main () {"
    "  gl_Position = vec4 (vp, 1.0);"
    "}";

    const char* fragment_shader =
    "#version 400\n"
    "out vec4 frag_colour;"
    "void main () {"
    "  frag_colour = vec4 (0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0);"
    "}";

    GLuint vs = glCreateShader (GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (vs, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader (vs);

GLint status = GL_TRUE;
glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);

    if(status != GL_TRUE) std::cout<<"VS FAILED\n";

    GLuint fs = glCreateShader (GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource (fs, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
    glCompileShader (fs);

status = GL_TRUE;
glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if(status != GL_TRUE) std::cout<<"PS FAILED\n";

    shader_programme = glCreateProgram ();
    glAttachShader (shader_programme, fs);
    glAttachShader (shader_programme, vs);
    glLinkProgram (shader_programme);
}


int main(int argc,  char * argv[])
{

    GLFWwindow* window;    
    int ver[3];
    glfwGetVersion(&ver[0], &ver[1], &ver[2]);
    std::cout << "major " <<ver[0] <<"minor: "<<ver[1]<<" ver: "<<ver[2];

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout << "Error";
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        std::cout << "Create window Error";
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);    
    std::cout<<"Version: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION);;

    initVertex();

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glPointSize(40.0f);
        glClearColor(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

        glUseProgram(shader_programme);
        glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(vao);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE, 0, 3);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the missing declaration for `glGenVertexArrays()`, you need to include `gl3.h` instead of `gl.h` to get GL3 level functionality:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
```

One problem I see in your code is that you use vertex attribute location `0` for setting up your coordinates. The attribute location is the first argument to `glEnableVertexAttribArray()` and `glVertexAttribPointer()`. But you don't really know that the location of `vp` in your shader program is `0`. The easiest way to ensure this is that you specify it directly in your shader code by extending the declaration of `vp`:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vp;
```

This works with GL 3.3 and higher. An alternative with older GL versions is to make the following API call **before** the `glLinkProgram()` call:

```
glBindAttribLocation(shader_programme, 0, "vp");
```

Comment: Only one small issue. I get a warning on including #include <OpenGL/gl3.h>....warning gl.h and gl3.h are both included.  Compiler will not invoke errors if using removed OpenGL functionality.
#include <iostream>
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <string.h>

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that before when my code includes `gl3.h`, and also includes headers from other toolkits that in turn include `gl.h`. I haven't found a very pretty solution for it. What I've done is include `gl3.h` before including the toolkit headers, and then define the header guard that prevents `gl.h` from being included (`#define __gl_h_`). Kind of ugly, but it does the job.